# Homeomorphism between pairs of letters

Tags: general-topology

How can I check if the pairs of letters T and K , E and W are homeomorphic or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the cut points.
They'll cut those letters into two or three pieces.
Determine the number of three piece cut points in each letter.